# How to save each image after divide it

Tags: image, matlab

How to save each image after divide it, below is my matlab code :

```
A = imread('MILD NPDR8.JPG');       %// size(384x512x3)
nCol = 2;                        %// number of Col blocks
nRow = 2;                        %// number of Row blocks
m = size(A,1)/nRow;              %// Sub-matrix row size (Should be an   integer)
n = size(A,2)/nCol;              %// Sub-matrix column size (Should be an integer)

imshow(A);                       %// show original image

out1 = reshape(permute(A,[2 1 4 3]),size(A,2),m,[],size(A,3));
out2 = permute(reshape(permute(out1,[2 1 3 4]),m,n,[],size(A,3)),[1 2 4 3]);

figure;
for i = 1:nCol*nRow
subplot(nRow,nCol,i); imshow(out2(:,:,:,i));
end
```

this is my result :
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuY34.jpg

Comment: Have you tried imsave? http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsave.html

Comment: i'm already try imsave but same also cannot save each image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MATLAB's imwrite function inside the for loop. 
The first variable should be the output image and the second one is the image name.
Use num2str to generate a unique file name to each image:

```
for i = 1:nCol*nRow
    subplot(nRow,nCol,i); imshow(out2(:,:,:,i));
    imwrite(out2(:,:,:,i),[num2str(i) '.jpg']);
end
```

Comment: How to save the figure that contains all image?